# Bootstrap: Create youtube-like top navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, youtube

I'm working with bootstrap and i want to create a 3-part sticky-top-navigation:

- Left part -  list with logo and glyphicons, floating left, static content (3 list items)
- Middle part -  list, dynamic list (rendering view), N items
- Right part -  list with logo and glyphicons, floating right, static content (3 list items)

I'm using navbar from bootstrap but i can't figure out how to center middle part of it.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-items" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="/img/logo.png"></a>
      </div>

      <div id="navbar-global-items" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

        <!-- LEFT MENU -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left global-nav-left">
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>  
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- RIGHT MENU -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- NEEDS TO BE CENTERED (*in the remaining space between left and right div*) -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        </ul>

      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Can you please help?

Comment: You need to post your code if you want to get a better answer to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code

```css
.navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    > li {
      float: none;
      display: inline-block;
    }
  }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Logo</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="pull-left"><a href="#">Example</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li class="social pull-right"><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li class="social pull-right"><a href="#">2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help jamdev.
But i need the centered part to be in some kind of div, so i can insert my list dynamically, through view.

 - Left part - <ul> list with logo and glyphicons, floating left, static content (3 list items)
 - Middle part - <ul> list, dynamic list (rendering view), N items
 - Right part - <ul> list with logo and glyphicons, floating right, static content (3 list items)

Comment: Works great, but..
My logo is too big, and 100% width of navbar-nav creates two rows.
I need it to be in the same row.
Can you please help?
Thanks @Jamdev

Comment: Thanks @Jamdev, but that code doesn't show logo when menu is not collapsed.